# How to call a method/function from another class file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried to make this function (and others) and put it in a separate class file in my project that's under "/Helpers/UploadFiles.cs"

```
namespace Artikelhantering.Helpers
{
public class UploadFiles
{

    private void EnsureDirectoriesExist(string SKU)
    {

        // if the directory doesn't exist - create it. 
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("//servername/wwwroot/prodimg/" + SKU))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("//servername/wwwroot/prodimg/" + SKU);
        }

    }
}
```

Then in the controller I added **using Artikelhantering.Helpers;**, it's also added to the namespace section of the web.config file and also to global.asa.cx.

Then I figured I could call it from an ActionResult in my controller like this

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _EnumerateFolder(string SKU)
        {
            // create directory if it does not exist
            EnsureDirectoriesExist(SKU);

            ViewBag.SKU = SKU;
            var folder = Directory.EnumerateFiles("//servername/wwwroot/prodimg/" + SKU);
            return View(folder);
        }
```

But all I get is:

**Error 2 The name 'EnsureDirectoriesExist' does not exist in the current context**

Tried calling it by writing it as UploadFiles.EnsureDirectoriesExist(); but that doesn't work either. How am I supposed to call these methods without having them all in the same file? I would like to organize this better.

Comment: EnsureDirectoriesExist is private,this method must be public

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is private. You can not access private members of other classes.

Also some other problems here:

1. The method you wrote is an instance method, so you need to have an instance of the class to call the method.
2. If you want to call it using `UploadFiles.EnsureDirectoryExists()`, you need to make it a class method (`static`).
3. I'm not sure whether you can create a new directory the way you try to do it. If you are trying to create the directory on the same machine that this code is running on, use local file names.

Sample code for 1):

```
UploadFiles uf = new UploadFiles();
uf.EnsureDirectoryExists();
```

Sample code for 2):

```
public class UploadFiles
{
    public static void EnsureDirectoriesExist(string SKU)
    {
        // if the directory doesn't exist - create it. 
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("//servername/wwwroot/prodimg/" + SKU))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("//servername/wwwroot/prodimg/" + SKU);
        }
    }
}
```

I furthermore suggest that you google for a C# tutorial that provides you with information on what classes are and how they can be used.

Comment: Yes it was private in he code I posted by mistake, I have it as public now, I was testing out random things to see what worked. I did the changes you said and it seems to work now, thanks! As for 3 I verified with another upload code that it did indeed work.

Comment: OK. The StackOverflow equivalent to *It tried what you said and it worked* is to upvote/accept the answer :-)

Comment: The updated sample code however does not work, this one I mean: `UploadFiles uf = new UploadFiles();
            uf.EnsureDirectoryExists();` And yes I will do that don't worry ;)

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*? I can't see any updated code in the question, so I can't properly answer to that.

Comment: I meant you updated your answer, you first had a different way of calling the function which I used successfully. As to the last error message. There where two errors: 1) a typo of the function name and 2) had to rename it to public void again instead of public static void in order to call it like that. if I put back static then I can call it like this `UploadFiles.EnsureDirectoriesExist(SKU);`

Comment: Yes. If you want to use the first sample, you can not use `static` (well you can, but you need not). `static` is needed if you don't want an object instance.

Answer (score 1):

First, change the access modifier of `EnsureDirectoriesExist` to public then
try to change your `ActionResult _EnumerateFolder` method with the code below:

```
public ActionResult _EnumerateFolder(string SKU)
{
    // create directory if it does not exist
    new UploadFiles.EnsureDirectoriesExist(SKU);

    ViewBag.SKU = SKU;
    var folder = Directory.EnumerateFiles("//servername/wwwroot/prodimg/" + SKU);
    return View(folder);
}
```

Comment: The method is private. It can't be called from outside the class.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenDittmar, I wasn't able to see that. I have updated my code now.

Answer (score 1):

1. First thing that is not correct here is a method [accessibility levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). In order to invoke method from outside of the class body it should be **public**.
2. Also, way that you are invoking this method is also incorrect. To do it in desired way you should make your class **static** to avoid creating an instance of a class to invoke method.

So:

```
public static class Helper 
{
      public static void EnsureDirectoriesExist(string SKU)
      {
           ...
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was just changing around stuff randomly with the private bit, it's back to public now. I have renamed the class & functions with static and it seems to have done the trick. I shall read up more on why this is important and what it does

Answer (score 0):

Mark your class as **static** then try this:

```
public static class UploadFiles
{

    public void EnsureDirectoriesExist(string SKU)
    {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public ActionResult _EnumerateFolder(string SKU)
{
        UploadFiles.EnsureDirectoriesExist(SKU);

        //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your directory method **public** and **static**. Then you can call it something like this

```
Artikelhantering.Helpers::UploadFiles.EnsureDirectoriesExist(SKU);
```

If you can't change the signature... you can make a public wrapper method and call it the same way. If you cannot make the method static, then you should create first an instance of your class and finally call the new public wrapper method.